# Convert Mac Timestamps with python

Tags: python, macos, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to convert Mac OSX (HFS Plus) timestamps to human readable format with python (on a linux system).

HFS Plus timestamps represent the time in seconds since midnight Jan 1, 1904.

For example, the timestamp: **3453120824**

In human date time: **Mon, 03 Jun 2013 16:13:44 GMT**

Is there a python way to do this?

Comment: if you can add 66 years worth of seconds to it, you can treat it like a regular `time.time()` call. I believe pythons `time.time()` is counting seconds from 1970 after doing some quick math.

Comment: i mean subtract 66 years lol***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just using [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) with [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)?  You'll want to pay particular attention to the list of formatting characters [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime("01-01-1904", "%m-%d-%Y")
>>> d
datetime.datetime(1904, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> d + datetime.timedelta(seconds=3453120824)
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 3, 16, 13, 44) 
>>> (d + datetime.timedelta(seconds=3453120824)).strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
'Mon, 03 Jun 2013 16:13:44 GMT'
```

Comment: This answer is good, in that it solves the hard part of the question, but IMO it could be improved by going the last step and showing how to print out the human readable date in the format that the OP asked about.

Comment: @MarkkuK. Just did that as you were commenting.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need datetime at all. Apple stores their times from the beginning of their time which is 2001-01-01. Super annoying but easy to overcome. Just add the difference between 1970-01-01 and 2001-01-01 in seconds to the variable and use time to format it like this in one line of code:

```
import time
mac_date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(data[0]/1000000000 + 978307200))
print mac_date
```

In this example data[0] is the date I got from doing a sqlite query against chat.db and it is the first field in the tuple. 978307200 is the difference between unix epoch and mac timestamp in seconds and that will never change. When you add those two together and convert unix epoch, you get a human readable date.

*As of High Sierra, the [chat.db file now uses nanoseconds.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114168/dates-format-in-messages-chat-db?newreg=0d28a9d2b8d3429985735d2ee52c3209) This requires the date value to be divided by 1000000000.

Comment: I tried your approach but it was always 12 hours off.
Did you see the same result?
I had to adjust:
978350457 - 12 * 60 * 60

Comment: yep, I had to use 978307200

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the other way around (datetime object to MAC Absolute Time) by this method:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(2013,6,3,16,13,44)
tmp = datetime.datetime(1904,1,1,0,0)
MacAbsTime = int((dt - tmp).total_seconds())
```

Also note that the iOS MAC Absolute Time is different to the OSX version, using the number of seconds since 1/1/2001 rather than 1904.

Comment: Your answer produces timestamp from datetime object. The question is about the opposite direction: get datetime object from timestamp.

Comment: True, but it was useful to me, might be useful for somebody else looking here